# Vala interface generics compiler error

Tags: generics, interface, compiler-errors, vala

I have the following small example(vala 0.18.1):

```
namespace Learning
{
   public interface IExample<T>
   {
      public abstract void set_to(T val);
      public abstract T get_to();
   }

   public class Example : Object, IExample<double>
   {
      private double to;

      public void set_to(double val)
      {
         to = val;
      }

      public double get_to()
      {
         return to;
      }

      public string to_string()
      {
         return "Example: %.5f".printf(to);
      }
   }

   public class Test
   {
      public static void main(string[] args)
      {
         stdout.printf("Start test\n");

         Example ex = new Example();

         stdout.printf("%s\n", ex.to_string());
         ex.set_to(5.0);
         stdout.printf("%s\n", ex.to_string());

         stdout.printf("End test\n");
      }
   }
}
```

This throws the error:

```
/src/Test.vala.c: In function ‘learning_test_main’:
/src/Test.vala.c:253:2: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘learning_iexample_set_to’
/src/Test.vala.c:117:6: note: expected ‘gconstpointer’ but argument is of type ‘double’
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Now from what little documentation I have been able to find on generics interfaces in Vala, http://www.vala-project.org/doc/vala-draft/generics.html#genericsexamples, this should work.  When I check the resulting C code, it shows the Example's set_to function as taking a double and the IExample's set_to function as taking a gconstpointer.

So why is the main function then using the gconstpointer version instead of the double version? Can some one explain to me why it does not work and a way to get around it?

Thank you for your help.

P.S. Yes I know the documentation found is a draft document.

ANSWER CODE:
According to the selected answer below this is what I changed the code to.

```
namespace Learning
{
   public interface IExample<T>
   {
      public abstract void set_to(T val);
      public abstract T get_to();
   }

   public class Example : Object, IExample<double?>
   {
      private double? to;

      public void set_to(double? val)
      {
         to = val;
      }

      public double? get_to()
      {
         return to;
      }

      public string to_string()
      {
         return (to == null) ? "NULL" : "Example: %.5f".printf(to);
      }
   }

   public class Test
   {
      public static void main(string[] args)
      {
         stdout.printf("Start test\n");

         Example ex = new Example();

         stdout.printf("%s\n", ex.to_string());
         ex.set_to(5.0);
         stdout.printf("%s\n", ex.to_string());

         stdout.printf("End test\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `IExample<double>`, use `IExample<double?>` to box the `double` so that it can be passed as a pointer. This necessary, generally, for any `struct` type in Vala. Classes and compact classes do not need this treatment, as they are already pointers. Also, `struct` types that are smaller than 32-bits (even on 64-bit platforms) such as `uint8` or `char` can be used directly without boxing. When in doubt, box.

Comment: Thank you. I took your answer and posted the version with code above. Thank you very much.